# Rails error message customization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a Rails 4 app and wish to improve the displayed error messages from model validations I'm attempting to update the locales `en-GB.yml` file as show below:

```
activemodel:
  errors:
    <<: *errors
activerecord:
  errors:
    <<: *errors
  attributes:
    batch:
      sampletype_id: "Sample type"
      process_id: "Process Identifier"
```

The batch model contains the following validation:

```
validates :sampletype_id, presence: true
```

Where `batch` is model and `sampletype_id` and `process_id` are model attributes.

these are not being picked up and used to build error messages eg.

`Sampletype can't be blank` rather than `Sample type can't be blank`

edit: trying to follow translations from http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models

edit2: yml pastbin http://pastebin.com/j1v9asww

Comment: Try `sampletype: "Sample type"` in your YAML file instead of the corresponding line.

Comment: The database field is actually called `sampletype_id` either way making the suggested change makes no difference.

Comment: Did you properly set `config.i18n.default_locale`?

Comment: I just deleted the `en-us.yml` file and replaced it with the `en-gb` one. Is any further configuration required?

Comment: Lots of information missing from the question. How are you calling the `translate` method? As @Sparda said, did you config your locale? Did you set up the model association properly?

Comment: The first level of your file should be the locale you're using, i.e. something like `en:` and `activerecord:` should be nested within it. Then in something like application.rb, check that you have a line like: `config.i18n.default_locale = :en`.

Comment: More like `config.i18n.default_locale = :"en-GB"`

Comment: +1 to @Mohamad from what I see in your pastebin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by updating the config line at the top of the YML file.

Thanks Mohamad!